# How can i get permission in my Application?

Tags: android, permissions

I need to use this `android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE` permission in my receive call activity. i get this error "Permission is only granted to system 
 apps"
anybody have solution??????

Answer (score 3):

It means that only apps with the same signature as the ROM can get this permission.

This means that you cannot get it, unless you create your own ROM for your device and sign the app with the same certificate as the ROM.